# Disable scroll down when spacebar is pressed on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I want to disable the scroll down when i pressed the spacebar. This only happens in firefox.

I already use overflow:hidden and meta tag viewport.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check the "related" sidebar on the right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343573/pressing-spacebar-moves-page-down

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This should do the trick. It states that when the spacebar is pressed on the page/document it doesn't just prevent its default behavior, but reverts back to original state.

return false seems to include preventDefault. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Check JQuery API's for more information about keydown events - http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) { 
    return !(e.keyCode == 32);
};
```

**JQuery example**

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:

As @amber-de-black stated "the above code will block pressing space key on HTML inputs". To fix this you `e.target` where exactly you want spacebar blocked. This can prevent the spacebar blocking other elements like HTML inputs.

In this case we specify the spacebar along with the body target. This will prevent inputs being blocked.

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32 && e.target == document.body) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

**NOTE**: If you're using JQuery use `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode` [Source](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/).

`The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode`

JQuery acts as a normalizer for a variety of events. If that comes to a surprise to anyone reading this. I recommend reading their [Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) documentation.

Comment: This code can block pressing space key on HTML input. You must check for (e.target === document.body) here full correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22559917/3120495

Answer (score 8):

Detect if the spacebar is being pressed. If it is, then prevent its default behaviour.

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if ( ( e.keycode || e.which ) == 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried capturing the keydown event in javascript? If you are using jQuery you can read more about capturing key events here: 
http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

If you aren't you can capture and ignore the space bar keypress as described here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2343597/1019092

Comment: @Alberto - be sure to read the part of the answer that says *"this is the expected behavior in most browsers. I use it all the time and I get extremely annoyed when it doesn't work in a page."*