# space bar works on android google chrome even when disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys I am using the following code which works fine on pc but for mobile google chrome browser users are able to use space bar which I have disabled.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function check(e) {
    var keynum
    var keychar
    var numcheck
    if (window.event) {
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e.which) {
        keynum = e.which;
    }
    keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
    if (keychar == " " || keychar == "'" || keychar == "`" || keychar =="!" || keychar =="@" || keychar =="#" || keychar =="$" || keychar =="%" || keychar =="^" || keychar =="&" || keychar =="*" || keychar =="(" || keychar ==")" || keychar =="-" || keychar =="+" || keychar =="=" || keychar =="/" || keychar =="~" || keychar =="<" || keychar ==">" || keychar =="," || keychar ==";" || keychar ==":" || keychar =="|" || keychar =="?" || keychar =="{" || keychar =="}" || keychar =="[" || keychar =="]" || keychar =="¬" || keychar =="£" || keychar =='"' || keychar =="\\") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

other than _ and - I wish nothing for user to enter even copy paste should be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible duplicate of [answer by Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559830/html-prevent-space-bar-from-scrolling-page)
I'm not sure how you're passing your event into your function but you can try using window.onkeydown and e.target on document.body as described.

Here is a snippet which might also help tidy your code?

```js
var keylist = [ "_", "-"];

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
   keychar = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
   if(keylist.indexOf(keychar)===-1 && e.target == document.body){
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: whats the usage i to use it on input filed?

Comment: this snippet applies to the global space of the window. if you want to register keypresses when you're in the input field then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365686/how-to-get-text-of-an-input-text-box-during-onkeypress