# javascript how to block space bar

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building an app, where I want to block the space bar from scrolling my page

I'm using VUE and I'm calling method using event handler

But calling keymonitor method throws me error:

> Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the `=>`

Do you know how to correctly call 'keymonitor' method?

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  return this.keymonitor(e)
})


keymonitor(event) {
  if (this.sendkey === 1) {
    if (event.key.length === 1) {
      this.keyDown = {
        cmd: 'keyboard',
        key: event.key,
      }
    } else if (
      event.key === 'Enter' ||
      event.key === 'Tab' ||
      event.key === 'PageUp' ||
      event.key === 'PageDown' ||
      event.key === 'End' ||
      event.key === 'Home' ||
      event.key === 'ArrowLeft' ||
      event.key === 'ArrowUp' ||
      event.key === 'ArrowRight' ||
      event.key === 'ArrowDown' ||
      event.key === 'Backspace' ||
      event.key === 'Delete' ||
      event.key === 'Escape'
    ) {
      this.keyDown = {
        cmd: 'keyboardSpecial',
        key: event.key,
      }
      // event.preventDefault();
    }
    console.log('eventkey: ')
    console.log(this.keyDown)
    this.sendMessage(this.keyDown)
  }
  if (event.which === 32) {
    console.log('SPACE')
  }
  return false
},
```

Comment: It might be asking you to do this: `window.addEventListener('keydown', e => this.keymonitor(e))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code instead - I am not too happy with the `this` here

```js
const keymonitor = event => {
  if (this.sendkey === 1) {
    if (event.key.length === 1) {
      this.keyDown = {
        cmd: 'keyboard',
        key: event.key,
      }
    } else if (
      event.key === 'Enter' ||
      event.key === 'Tab' ||
      event.key === 'PageUp' ||
      event.key === 'PageDown' ||
      event.key === 'End' ||
      event.key === 'Home' ||
      event.key === 'ArrowLeft' ||
      event.key === 'ArrowUp' ||
      event.key === 'ArrowRight' ||
      event.key === 'ArrowDown' ||
      event.key === 'Backspace' ||
      event.key === 'Delete' ||
      event.key === 'Escape'
    ) {
      this.keyDown = {
        cmd: 'keyboardSpecial',
        key: event.key,
      }
      // event.preventDefault();
    }
    console.log('eventkey: ')
    console.log(this.keyDown)
    this.sendMessage(this.keyDown)
  }
  if (event.which === 32) {
    console.log('SPACE')
    event.preventDefault()
  }
  return false
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', keymonitor)
```

Comment: I've changed calling method as you've showed, but it seems, that "return false" doesn't works, because spacebar still scroll my page. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you try the `event.preventDefault()` I added?

Comment: event.preventDefault() works perfect. How to disable it if i will need to?

Comment: Use a toggle
`if (disableSpace) event.preventDefault()` and set disableSpace somewhere

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", keymonitor);
```

Keymonitor will automatically get the event as a parameter if you define it as a param in the function, which you did

Make sure to add the window.addEvenListener after the function keymonitor. Otherwise it'll be out of scope. Since it won't exist yet.

To actually prevent a key from working:

```
if (event.which === 32) {
    console.log('SPACE')
    event.preventDefault();
  }

return false;
```

Comment: i did it, but somehow spacebar still works (scroll page), what means that "return false" doesn't works. Do you know why?

Comment: @mplungjan I was just answering the question that was asked in the comments. Didn't even look at your post... I can't help it that that's the way it's done in Javascript

Comment: It is always useful to reload and read other answers before adding stuff. You never know if the answer you are about to write is identical to someone else's and can be deleted

Comment: That's a learning point for me. Will do that for sure next time :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simplified working example for you, inspired by [HTML prevent space bar from scrolling page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559830/html-prevent-space-bar-from-scrolling-page).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
      if (e.keyCode == 32 && e.target == document.body) {
        alert('prevented spacebar on body');
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input />
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```