# While navigating using Tab button on a web page only when at a anchor tag link, I want to make spacebar act as a enter key click

Tags: javascript, html, css

When using tab button to navigate through page, when curser is at anchor tag link and on entering space button when at anchor tag link, I have to make the space button act as a enter key click using JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable scroll down when spacebar is pressed on firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522864/disable-scroll-down-when-spacebar-is-pressed-on-firefox)

Comment: @Robiseb after preventing default behaviour, I want space bar to work as a enter key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable / disable the key listener as you want, for exemple when an input is focused.

Do like this

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.addEventListener('focus', function(){
  disableSpace(false);
});
input.addEventListener('blur', function(){
  disableSpace(true);
});

function disableSpace(enable){
 $(window).keypress(function(e) {
  if (!enable) return true;
  if (e.keyCode === 0 || e.keyCode === 32) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('space pressed');
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" >
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm showing it using jQuery, the principle is the same - add a listener to the space key press, prevent default behaviour and call the function you'd like to use -

```
$(window).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 0 || e.keyCode === 32) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('space pressed') // here comes your logic
  }
});
```