# Pressing space on iframe scrolls parent page down, how to prevent that without breaking keyup event

Tags: javascript

My iframe game is reading the keyboard including space,  but on some browsers (Firefox, Safari) pressing Space also scrolls my page down, that causes my game to partially go out of screen.   Sometimes it seems the page even scrolls back up when some other keys are pressed...

My game handles keypresses on "keyup" event.

```
input.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
//game handles all keys including space here
}
```

Because of using keyup event, this answer is not suitable to prevent space ;
[Pressing spacebar scrolls page down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343573/pressing-spacebar-scrolls-page-down)

If I add this code, my game does not receive keyup events:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) { 
  return !(e.keyCode == 32);
};
```

When I add this code above to parent html page, having ifreme,  it only works if keyboard focus is clicked to parent html.  When focus is inside iframe, the code does not work.
It seems above code fixed issue for Safari!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML prevent space bar from scrolling page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559830/html-prevent-space-bar-from-scrolling-page)

Comment: Thanks,  the game is inside iframe,  I added this code to parent html and it seems to work there IF keyboard focus is first clicked to parent html, outside of game.  When the keyb focus is in inside the game,     the code does not work

Comment: is the iframe with the same origin?

Comment: @Tom Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onkeypress` event fires the browser scrolling. You can call `preventDefault` in this event, and the `keyup` and `keydown` events will continue to fire as intended.

```
window.onkeypress = function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};

window.onkeyup = function(e) { 
  console.log("Space key up!")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `preventDefault`

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

See this codepen for a demo: https://codepen.io/xurei/pen/MWyveEp

Comment: Thanks, yes this removes the space feature from browser,  but problem is that I have iframe on this same page,  now my content there inside iframe is no more able to receive space, it uses this code:
                window.onkeypress = akeyPress;
  window.onkeydown = akeyDown;
  window.onkeyup = akeyUp;

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the right window object first

```
function getIframeWindow(iframe_object) {
  var doc;

  if (iframe_object.contentWindow) {
    return iframe_object.contentWindow;
  }

  if (iframe_object.window) {
    return iframe_object.window;
  } 

  if (!doc && iframe_object.contentDocument) {
    doc = iframe_object.contentDocument;
  } 

  if (!doc && iframe_object.document) {
    doc = iframe_object.document;
  }

  if (doc && doc.defaultView) {
   return doc.defaultView;
  }

  if (doc && doc.parentWindow) {
    return doc.parentWindow;
  }

  return undefined;
}

var myFrame = document.getElementById('targetFrame');
var frame_win = getIframeWindow(myFrame);
```

and then add the listeners to stop the spacebar event from bubbling up.

```
if (frame_win) {

  var preventSpace = (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    };

  frame_win.addEventListener('keydown', preventSpace);
  frame_win.addEventListener('keyup', preventSpace);
  frame_win.addEventListener('keypress', preventSpace);
}
```