# Javascript disable spacebar scrolling

Tags: javascript

I am working on a WebGL application and I use the spacebar for movement of the camera. The problem is, when I press the spacebar the website also scrolls down. Is there a way to disable this feature?

None of the answers so far works reliably. They work for about a second, then the site scrolls down for a tiny amount of time and then the cycle repeats.

This is my code for the keypresses:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) =>  {
    if(e.repeat) { return; }

    if(e.which == 27 || e.which == 9) {
        document.exitPointerLock();
        checkMouse = false;
    }

    if(checkMouse) {
        if(e.which == 87) { forwardPressed = true; }
        if(e.which == 83) { backwardPressed = true; }
        if(e.which == 65) { leftPressed = true; }
        if(e.which == 68) { rightPressed = true; }
        if(e.which == 32) { upPressed = true; event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); }
        if(e.which == 16) { downPressed = true; }
    }
});
```

As you can see, for the space key there already is one solution implemented but both types of answers I have gotten so far don't work.

Comment: Duplicate of [Pressing spacebar scrolls page down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343573/pressing-spacebar-scrolls-page-down)

Comment: @GuyIncognito That doesn't work reliably

Comment: You need to mention in the question what solutions you've tried and what exact problems  you've hade with them. Otherwise you can't avoid getting generic solutions to the stated problem.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I'm pretty sure there is a generic solution to this problem, but the answers so far just haven't worked reliably.

Comment: The generic, reliable solution is in the duplicate. If it doesn't work for you, you have some other code that's interfering with it.

Comment: @GuyIncognito so I added some of my code...

Comment: `if(e.repeat) { return; }` <-- this is obviously preventing the code to do `event.preventDefault()` later if you hold the spacebar down.

Comment: ...and this is a prime example why you should always show your code when it doesn't work, instead of insisting that everyone else is wrong.

Comment: @GuyIncognito And that also is a prime example why you shouldn't just close a question because its about a topic that already has been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

    if(keycode == '32') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work reliably. Every second it scrolls down  bit

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your javascript:

```
let checkMouse = true
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) =>  {
if(e.repeat) { 

    return; 
}

if(e.which == 27 || e.which == 9) {
    document.exitPointerLock();
    checkMouse = false;
}

if(checkMouse) {
    if(e.which == 87) { forwardPressed = true; }
    if(e.which == 83) { backwardPressed = true; }
    if(e.which == 65) { leftPressed = true; }
    if(e.which == 68) { rightPressed = true; }
    if(e.which == 32) { upPressed = true; event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); }
    if(e.which == 16) { downPressed = true; }
}
if (e.which == 32) {
    return !(e.keyCode == 32);
}
});
```

checkMouse wasn't initialised before. It's working fine here.

Comment: As already said in the comments under the question this doesn't work reliably

Comment: Worked for me, there must be some conflict, share your code.

Comment: I added some code

Comment: made some update.

Comment: Of course checkMouse is initialised